# NuxtJS and $fetch: How to fetch and play audio when first chunk is ready?

Tags: fetch-api, html5-audio, web-audio-api, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt server route that returns streamable audio from a third party API. I am using $fetch on the client side to  send a POST request to that Nuxt server route and return a readablestream.

How can I do the following:

1. Get the readable stream in chunks
2. Let the user play the audio on the client as soon as the first chunk is available?

Here's my working code:

`/server/api/generate-text-to-speech.post.ts`:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { text } = await readBody(event)
  const response = await $fetch(
    'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/EXAVITQu4vr4xnSDxMaL/stream',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      responseType: 'stream',
      headers: {
        accept: 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'xi-api-key': useRuntimeConfig().XI_API_KEY // creator version
      },
      body: {
        text: text,
        model_id: 'eleven_monolingual_v1',
        voice_settings: {
          stability: 0.5,
          similarity_boost: 0.75,
          style: 0,
          use_speaker_boost: true
        }
      }
    }
  )
  console.log('server route api: ', response)
  setResponseHeader(event, 'Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
  return response
})
```

This provides the following response:
`ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`

The client fetches this like so:

```
const generateSpeech = async (formattedStory) => {
    formattedStory = "In this heartfelt tale, a young pig named Pippin forms an unexpected friendship with a small spider named Silky. Pippin is initially afraid of Silky, but through mutual kindness and understanding, they become inseparable friends. The story gently explores themes of friendship, empathy, and overcoming fears. <break time='2.0s' /> The Tale of Pippin and Silky <break time='1.5s' /> Once upon a time, in a peaceful farm nestled in the countryside, lived a young pig named Pippin. Pippin was a joyful and curious piglet, but there was one thing he feared more than anything - spiders. One day, while exploring the farm, Pippin discovered a small spider, no bigger than a button, in his favorite mud puddle. Do you remember a time when you were afraid of something? What helped you overcome your fear? <break time='3.0s' /> The spider was Silky, a tiny, friendly creature who had spun a delicate web across the corner of the puddle. Pippin squealed in fright and backed away, but Silky only waved her eight legs in a friendly manner. Pippin was surprised. He had always imagined spiders to be scary and mean, but Silky didn't seem to be either of those things. She seemed... kind. Has there been a time when something wasn't as scary as you first thought? <break time='3.0s' /> Feeling braver, Pippin took a step closer and introduced himself. Silky replied in her soft, sweet voice, 'Hello, Pippin'! I mean no harm."

    try {
        const response = await $fetch("/api/generate-text-to-speech", {
            method: "POST",
            responseType: 'stream',
            body: {
                text: formattedStory
            },
            onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
                console.log('onResponse: ', response)
                // Get reader here to read chunks?
                // How to bind it to audio element so user can play it?
            }
        })
        console.log('from client: ', response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Speech generation failed: ", error);
    }
}
```

The above code returns the following:

```
onResponse:  Response {_data: ReadableStream, type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/generate-text-to-speech', redirected: false, status: 200, …}
 from client:  ReadableStream {locked: true}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.